# Generate HTML file from rspec

Tags: rspec

How do I generate an HTML report from rspec?

Answer (score 27):

Building off the previous answer, its pretty simple:

```
rspec /directory/containing/specs/** --format h > output.html
```

I run this from the root of my rails app with the following path spec/**.
I hope that helps. If you have non "_spec.rb" files in there you might need to modify the path argument.

Comment: The problem I have with using "> out.html" instead of "--out out.html" is that the rspec command is echoed to the HTML file as well, above the `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 15):

we could add

```
--format html
--out rspec_results.html
```

to .rspec

so rspec will write result to rspec_results.html

see https://coderwall.com/p/gfmeuw

Answer (score 8):

RSpec has a command line option to produce html formatted output:

```
rspec <path_to_spec_file> --format html
```

Comment: bascially my problem is that i want to generate html report of my all test cases of all controllers in single html file.Is this possible to generate a report????

Answer (score 4):

From https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/format-option

**Scenario**: multiple formats

When I run `rspec example_spec.rb --format progress --format documentation --out rspec.txt`

Then the output should contain ".F*"

And the file "rspec.txt" should contain:

```
something does something that passes does something that fails (FAILED - 1) does something that is pending (PENDING: No reason given)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-o` or `--out` option to specify the output file.

Use the `-f` or `--format` option to specify the format

```
rspec spec/* --format html --out report.html
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Jenkins then look into the XUNIT plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rspec_html_formatter` gem to generate pretty RSpec html reports. See https://github.com/kingsleyh/rspec_reports_formatter for implementation.

`rspec -f RspecHtmlFormatter spec`