# How can we generate html file from rspec

Tags: rspec

hii guys,

I have a query that i want to generate a html report of all my test cases of all controllers..

Is this possible in rspec??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we generate html file from rspec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496664/how-can-we-generate-html-file-from-rspec)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about rspec, but rdoc seems to do exactly what you're asking about. http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/