# looking for a GUI for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'd like to make a list of all tests that are failing and passing for the dev team (myself included) to look at. Is there anything pre-built that gets me closer to that goal?

from my gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "rspec", '>=2'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496664/how-can-we-generate-html-file-from-rspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is a Continuous Integration Server. The most popular ones are probably Travis-CI (hosted) and Jenkins.

- [Using Jenkins With Rails](http://danseaver.com/blog/2011/11/22/using-jenkins-with-rails/)
- take a look at [travis-ci.org](http://travis-ci.org/)

**EDIT**: As @Dave Newton told in the question's comments, the OP might want something simpler like this: [How can we generate html file from rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496664/how-can-we-generate-html-file-from-rspec)

Comment: i think a CI server's a bit beyond the scope of what I want. This seems to help a lot. I'll try it out shortly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496664/how-can-we-generate-html-file-from-rspec

Comment: just modified my answer to include @DaveNewton's answer