# Saving errors/exceptions to a log file using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am doing a point to point remote Rails API testing using RSpec. I would like to log all errors and exceptions when RSpec is running into a log file. Is this possible? Would also like it to be formatted well. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This SO thread should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496664/generate-html-file-from-rspec

Comment: Is there a way to also output the JSON object being sent and received during integration specs?

Answer (score 0):

```
 bundle exec rspec spec 2> errors_exceptions.log
```