# InSpec/RSpec output HTML format

Tags: rspec, inspec

How can `rspec_html_formatter gem` be used with `InSpec` to generate output in html format? 
Also, is it possible to edit the output shown when we use `html` format in inspec?

`inspec exec spec.rb --format html`

Can we just show whatever is in `control` statement and not every individual test with this command?

Comment: Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496664/generate-html-file-from-rspec

Comment: Yes it works, but the problem is it represents all the tests. I just want to see whatever is there in `control` statements and not all individual tests as this creates a problem for me because suppose I have 50 tests in 10 control statements. I want to see those 10 and all 50.